# Tensorflow random seed not working

Tags: python, random, tensorflow, random-seed

I have following code snippet in my project

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(1)

  # Here are the dictionary of weights and biases of each layer
        weights = {
            'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev=STDDEV, seed=1)),
            'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], stddev=STDDEV, seed=1)),
        }

        biases = {
            'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], seed=1)),
            'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], seed=1))
        }

 init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Launch session
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init_op)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            randidx = np.random.randint(int(TRAIN_SIZE), size=BATCH_SIZE)
            batch_xs = data_train[randidx, :]
            batch_ys = labels_train[randidx, :]
            # Fit using batched data
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, dropout_keep_prob: 0.9})
            # Calculate average cost
            avg_cost += sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, dropout_keep_prob: 1.}) / total_batch
```

As you can see I have set random set at the top and each time I run this code it generates different results. Why my random seed not working.

Comment: It should generate different results as thats the point. If you need to save the weights/bias values use the save/restore functionality. The same seed value will not help:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed

Comment: no, the point of using random seed is to generate same numbers over and over

Comment: Yah, they are same on one singe run, but on each different run it will generate different random numbers. This is why you need to save the values and restore them in consecutive runs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow generate random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235738/tensorflow-generate-random-seed)